# Python: "for" loops creates empty from previous result on appending

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is general goal: i need a list of all doubles combination.
Here is what happened: next append to Output variable cleaning previous result.

Main code:

```
mainArray = ["Value1", "Value2", "Value3", "Value4", "Value5", "Value6"]

result = []

def combine():
    for x in mainArray:        
        for i in mainArray:
            temp = []
            temp.append(x)
            temp.append(i)
            if temp[0] != temp[1]:
                result.append(temp)
                print(result)
            temp.clear()



combine()
print("Output Result: ", result)
```

Console output:

```
$py comp.py
True
[['Value1', 'Value2']]
[[], ['Value1', 'Value3']]
[[], [], ['Value1', 'Value4']]
[[], [], [], ['Value1', 'Value5']]
[[], [], [], [], ['Value1', 'Value6']]
[[], [], [], [], [], ['Value2', 'Value1']]
[[], [], [], [], [], [], ['Value2', 'Value3']]
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], ['Value2', 'Value4']]
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], ['Value2', 'Value5']]
//etc
Output Result:  [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```

Comment: What do you expect `temp.clear()` to do if not clear the list you just appended?

Comment: All of this can be simplified to `result = [[x, y] for x in mainArray for y in mainArray if x != y]`.

Answer (score 1):

You should rather use standard library [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) for this.

```
import itertools

mainArray = ["Value1", "Value2", "Value3", "Value4", "Value5", "Value6"]
print(list(itertools.combinations(mainArray, 2)))
# [('Value1', 'Value2'), ('Value1', 'Value3'), ('Value1', 'Value4'), ('Value1', 'Value5'), ('Value1', 'Value6'), ('Value2', 'Value3'), ('Value2', 'Value4'), ('Value2', 'Value5'), ('Value2', 'Value6'), ('Value3', 'Value4'), ('Value3', 'Value5'), ('Value3', 'Value6'), ('Value4', 'Value5'), ('Value4', 'Value6'), ('Value5', 'Value6')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `temp.clear()` from your code.

```
mainArray = ["Value1", "Value2", "Value3", "Value4", "Value5", "Value6"]

result = []

def combine():
    for x in mainArray:        
        for i in mainArray:
            temp = []
            temp.append(x)
            temp.append(i)
            if temp[0] != temp[1]:
                result.append(temp)



combine()
print("Output Result: ", result)
```

When you append an object to a list, the list doesn't get a separate copy of that item. So if you clear the object after adding to a list, it will get cleared in the contents of the list as well.

Answer (score 1):

The result.append(temp) line doesn't make a copy of the temp, it just appends a reference, one you are clearing a few lines below. You can do result.append(temp[:]) to create a copy, but Dušan Maďar is right, don't do it yourself, you have a ready to use library to do this.

Edit: posted at the same time the previous reply has been posted, yep, removing temp.clear() is enough, temp = [] creates a new list every time, you pass it into append, and that should work just fine.

Comment: You have the wrong bracket in your `append` call. Also, I think it would be more common to use `temp.copy()`.

Comment: Wrong bracket edited. Kinda makes me wonder if temp.copy() is any different from temp[:], performance-wise.

Answer (score 0):

arrays are mutable data type so when you modify an array which contains another array, it will affect the value

eg

```
array= [1,2,3]
result= []
result.append(array)
print(result)
#[[1,2,3]]
array.append(4)
print(result)
#[[1,2,3,4]]
```

to solve your problem you can append a copy of the array instead using `array.copy()`

```
mainArray = ["Value1", "Value2", "Value3", "Value4", "Value5", "Value6"]

result = []

def combine():
    for x in mainArray:        
        for i in mainArray:
            temp = []
            temp.append(x)
            temp.append(i)
            if temp[0] != temp[1]:
                result.append(temp.copy())
                print(result)
            temp.clear()



combine()
print("Output Result: ", result)
```